# Simplified and Traditional Chinese characters in CJK

Tags: cjk

I am using `CJK` package to create a tex file based on a traditional Chinese doc file. Sometimes other people may mistakenly type some simplified Chinese Characters in the doc file. I realize some simplified Chinese characters do not show in a traditional Chinese environment:

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi} 
...
\end{CJK}
```

Is there a way to get simplified Chinese characters generated in a similar environment with `CJK` package?

For some limitations, I have to use `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3):

You could switch to a different engine, in this case `xelatex`, which I think makes it easier to handle fonts and also other languages. In the case of languages like Chinese, Japanese and Korean, you can load the appropriately named `xeCJK` package.

When using `xelatex`, you can load the `fontspec` package and then use `\setmainfont{}` to set the document font. By the same token, with the previously named package, you can also load the command `\setCJKmainfont{}` and load a font specifically for your language, for example I used Heiti TC, where the T stands for Traditional (there's also Heiti SC). But you could use any font that is designed for Traditional Chinese.

Here's what it looks like with a Chinese Lorem Ipsum, although I cannot post the body code with the Chinese part, because it's blocked and I cannot post it.

[image: example image]

And here's the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{Heiti TC}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know `xelatex` can do better but because of some limitation, I have to use `pdflatex`. Are there any methods to process them in `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, `\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi}` is not a "traditional Chinese" environment. It does not show simplified chinese characters because the font here, `bsmi`, contains only traditional Chinese  characters. To typeset simplified Chinese, one has to load corresponding font, such as `gbsn`. (This time, traditional Chinese characters are not shown.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [`ctex` package](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/language/chinese/ctex/ctex.pdf)? You'd only need to load the package and type away...

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

简体中文，简体中文；简体中文。

繁體中文，繁體中文；繁體中文。
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Does it work with `pdflatex`? I tried in Mac but seems not working

Comment: @Joe: Yes, it does. What error message are you getting?

Comment: `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/fontset/ctex-fontset-fandol.def:96: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! [  }]`
`pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file cyberb9a): Font cyberb9a at 632 not found
Check the TeX log file for more information` I use ST2 and Mac.

Comment: @Joe: So it seems to be a problem related to fonts. You may want to post a question with a minimal working example about this. That way it's easier to detect the problems.

Answer (score 0):

問題不是怎麼用簡體字。
真的問題是怎麼修理檔所以只用正體字。
你可能用opencc自動換:

Why not mend the problem rather than the symptom? Pipe the file through   `opencc` (package `opencc-tools` on Fedora) before running LaTeX:

```
$ cat source.tex | opencc > source.proper.tex

$ latex source.proper.tex
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!